# What should I do when I don't need to use all the parameters of a function?

Tags: c++

I made a function

```
size_t CalculusWizard::parseDouble(const std::string & str, std::string::const_iterator start, double & d)
```

for a wide variety of uses. My particular use at the moment only needs its returned value, which doesn't depend at all on the parameter `double & d`. So what I did in my code was make a variable `dummy` that is just there as a formality:

```
double * dummy = new double;
if (parseDouble(fx, fx.begin(), *dummy) == fx.size())
    fx = "c";
delete dummy;
```

Is that what I should do? Any suggestions on how to better approach this type of scenario?

Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: I'm new to c++, but I don't think you'll need a `new` just to satisfy `double & d`. Just pass a variable without allocating on the heap, and the compiler probably will just optimize away any unused variables.

Comment: Yea, but I need "new" so that I can clear the variable "dummy" when I'm done using it. If I don't use "new", then "dummy" sticks around until its block is done executing.

Comment: But then the pointer to your double will stick around until the block is done executing, so there's no gain there.

Comment: You can control the lifetime of your objects by using `{` and `}` scoping, so you don't have to wait until the whole blocks ends.

Comment: Heap operations (`new` and `delete`) are expensive - much more expensive than an extra 8 bytes of memory (for a `double`) on the stack.

Answer (score 4):

You could create another parseDouble method with a different set of parameters (ie, not the double & d).

One other option would be to use the facade design pattern, and leave the complex task of parsing the double to a private method and create a subset of methods accepting the right amount of parameters for each of your needs.

You could also (as the previous poster said) use default values, although i personnaly dislike them because it encourages the use of "non-standard behaviours" to me.

Answer (score 2):

It would be neater/cleaner if you did:

```
double dummy = 0.0;
if (parseDouble(fx, fx.begin(), dummy) == fx.size())
    fx = "c";
```

This way you don't have to worry about cleaning up the memory (what if `parseDouble` throws an exception? you'll leak the memory you allocated for `dummy`).

To remove `dummy` before the end of the block, you can do this using scoping:

```
{ // Start new scope.
    double dummy = 0.0;
    if (parseDouble(fx, fx.begin(), dummy) == fx.size())
        fx = "c";
} // dummy gets destroyed here.
```

Comment: Even better, `double dummy{};`

Comment: @user1095108 Just because it's newer doesn't make it better. You are merely obfuscating the code.